# How to set fixed yaxis bounds in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to have a fixed Y-axis, with a minimum of -0.2 and a maximum of 0.5.
I tried things like:

```
p = Bar(data, 'key_0', values='values', y_range=(-0.2, 0.5))
p.yaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[-0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.5])
p.yaxis.bounds = (-0.2, 0.5)
```

But if the max y value in my dataset is 0.3, the y axis won't go higher and stop at 0.3.

How can I fix the bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem, apparently the options I tried don't apply to a bar chart generated with the `Bar()` function.

Here is my solution:

```
p= figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=400, y_range=(-0.2, 0.5))
# setting bar values
h = values
# Correcting the bottom position of the bars to be on the 0 line.
adj_h = h/2
# add bar renderer
p.rect(x=x, y=adj_h, width=0.8 , height=h)
```